# How to fix 'javah' error to create JNI folder when using NDK with Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, webcam, javah

I Create a WebCam based Android Application. I follow a [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kFtxo7rr2HQ) video to create JNI to support my project. But i will show error on creating a JNI folder in parent directory.

When i compile the code in compiler

```
D:\SRINIVASAN\WebCam_Android\SudharsWebCam\app\src\main>javah -d jni -classpath D:\Android-New\platforms\android-19\android.jar;.. \ ..\build\intermediates\classes\debug com.example.sudharsanc.sudharswebcam.CameraPreview
```

It shows error as

> javah is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

Some of questions which the same already in stackoverflow , but it will not help to get the solutions.

Guide me.
**Thanks in Advance.**.

Comment: Have you added on environment Variables -> System Variables something like -> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31 ?

Comment: `javah` is part of JDK. You can add the JDK\bin directory to PATH, then your command will succeed.

Comment: Ya, added the path in environment variable. But agin it will shown the error as **Could not find class file for 'com.example.sudharsanc.sudharswebcam.CameraPreview** .

Comment: After making small changes in Environment variable my project support **javah** . Now it will shown new error during the time of creating jni directory. **Problem is :**  Error: cannot access android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
  class file for android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity not found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer to create jni folder using compiler javah command in android studio.

Follow the [steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuOz5.png)